# .net 4.5 API Integration tests in Azure pipeline

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops, integration-testing, api-design

We have an API project written in .net 4.5 and we are writing integration tests with xunit in order to eliminate the need to test API manually through postman. We have created a number of tests that check our Get/Post/Put/Delete endpoints. We are not using mocks since we want to see if the data is going to be saved/retrieved in/from the database properly. Each test method is using HttpClient object to make calls to retrieve the test/result data for assertions.

Now we would like to add these tests to an azure pipeline. We can currently run them locally only from within the visual studio 2019 (we are connecting to the actual database on the server, but the API is running locally). The problem is that tests are being run during the build in Azure pipeline and as I mentioned we use HTTP Client like this:

```
var response = await _client.PostAsync("http://api_url", parameters, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

and then we use the response object for assertions. So we need the API to be already running on our dev server. But since tests run during the build pipeline the API changes are not there yet (they are not supposed to be until they pass the tests). Is there a way to create a container during the azure build pipeline execution or something like that to allows us to run these tests in the form they are in now?

Comment: Are you bound to .NET Framework 4.5 or is it an option to migrate to .NET Core? ASP.NET Core has a pretty cool feature called `TestServer` which hosts your complete web API within the test. You can of course use `HttpClient`, but under the hood, there is no actual HTTP call. Instead, it's a pure method call.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm bound to .net 4.5 for now. We are planning migrations, but that's not going to happen anytime soon. I'm reading about TestServer and I was hoping that some older versions of it could be working with .net 4.5. But from what you say it seems like a feature bound to .net core only

Comment: Would it be possible to introduce a designated integration test environment, to which you deploy first, where you can run the tests on, before deploying to the dev environment?

Comment: So I see three options: 1 - test the controller classes directly instead using the `_client`. 2 - Mock the `HttpMessageHandler` of `_client`. 3 - Use a Windows container

Comment: yadejo I am considering such option, but I'm still looking for other solutions. @mu88 Thanks for the advice. I actually have some hopes to find documentation for TestServer. I looked through nuget packages and versions 2 and below seem to have dependencies of net framework 4.0 and 4.5 so maybe there is a way to use it with .net 4.5 config class/file. As for now, I've only seen use presentation of TestServer for .net core though

Comment: AFAIK you should be able to reference assemblies targeting .NET Framework from within a .NET Core project. So maybe you can spawn a little .NET Core TestServer and reuse the controllers from your .NET Framework assembly.

Comment: The problem is that I wanted the test project to be .net core but I had issues with compatibility and had to settle with .net 4.5 for the test project as well.  It seems the HttpServer object can be created and supplied a config. The thing is that there are also bundle configs, filter configs and Dependency injection. I only found how to use HttpServer object with just HttpConfiguration setup. and that's the only one being supplied for HttpServer object so I'm afraid we will run into problems due to lack of filters, DI and bundles configuration.